# Convergence of value iteration

Tags: algorithms, markov-process, artificial-intelligence

Why is the termination condition of the value-iteration algorithm ( example http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/probability/mdp/search/ValueIteration.java ) as it is?

In the MDP (Markov Decision Process) we have

$||U_{i+1}-U_i||< \text{error}\cdot(1-\gamma)/\gamma$, where

$U_i$ is a vector of utilities
$U_{i+1}$ is the vector of updated utilities
$\text{error}$ is the error bound used in the algorithm
$\gamma$ is the discount factor used in the algorithm

- Where does "$\text{error}\cdot(1-\gamma)/\gamma$" come from?
- Is the term "$/\gamma$"  because every step is discounted by $\gamma$? But then what about $\text{error}\cdot(1-\gamma)$?
- And how big must $\text{error}$ be?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain what you're discussing, expand abbreviations on first use, and otherwise make it as obvious as you can to use what is going on. Are you talking about a Markov decision process?

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: I have edited as best I can. Please check that I haven't changed your meaning, and edit to fix as necessary.

Comment: thx for editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the basic convergence proof of value iteration.  To state the result using your notation,

$||U_{\infty}-U_i|| < \epsilon/2$ whenever $||U_{i+1}-U_i|| < \epsilon(1-\gamma)/2\gamma$ $\hspace{2cm}$ with $\gamma <1$

We are bounding the overall error of the value iteration this way, not just terminating the algorithm when successive iterations differ by less than some value $\delta$- which, without the convergence proof, would not provide an upper bound on the overall error.

Clearly this is more useful than just stopping at some user-specified $||U_{i+1}-U_i||$, where the user has to do the work to convert from the $\delta$ to the bound (or the reverse.)

For the proof itself, see [Puterman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471727822) 161-163.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about the error value? How big must it be?

Comment: I assume you mean $\epsilon$.  That's really up to you.  A disadvantage of value iteration w.r.t. policy iteration is that when using the latter, if you get two consecutive iterations with the same policy, you've converged to the optimum policy.  With value iteration, however, you can't be sure (w/o a lot of extra work, and often not even then) that even the tiniest error in the final $U_i$ wouldn't be enough to push you into a different policy choice.  Nonetheless, if you want a solution that's guaranteed within $\epsilon$ of optimum, use that value in the program.

Comment: the explanation is understandable, but the proof is still unclear, and as I understand this termination condition comes from the proof.

Comment: ||Vγ(dE)infinity−V(n+1)||<=(γ/1-γ)*||V(n+1)-Vn|| where does dE comes from? Puterman says it is some argmax function and how in proof it can be equal to Vγ(dE)infinity==L(Vγ(dE)infinity), as I understand L is bellman update

Comment: The idea is that you only use the value functions which correspond to the best policy (given the previous iteration's result).  The dE part is the arg max V(policy), i.e., the best policy.  The point is that it's not just a bound on the error of the current estimate of the value function given the current policy, it's a bound on the overall suboptimality of the current policy relative to the long run discounted value of the best policy.

Comment: Can you where does error⋅(1−γ)/γ" come from? Any proof?

Comment: I already gave you the source of the proof - Puterman's Markov Decision Processes, pp. 161-162.  The proof uses the Banach Fixed-Point Theorem, which, in specialized form, is presented on p. 150.

Comment: I saw it, but where is <= γ^n*(1-γ^m)/(1-γ) ||v^1-v^0||

Comment: if we take ||v^1-v^0||  equals "error", m=1 for Vn+1-Vn, we will have ||Un+1−Un||<=error*γ^n

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking any more.  As it states, if 6.3.3 holds, then the overall error is bounded by $\epsilon$.  If you have a discount rate of $\gamma$ and you want your error to be bounded by $\epsilon$, then iterate until $|U_{i+1}-U_i| < \epsilon(1-\gamma)/2\gamma$.  The proof of this is the not-very-many lines from the very bottom of page 161 to the middle of page 162.  It states quite clearly "rearranging terms yields" for one part and "applying a similar argument to that used to derived (6.2.11)..." for the other part.  Not at all clear what you want to know.

Comment: γ^n*(1-γ^m)/(1-γ) ||v^1-v^0|| - is the end of Banach theorem on p.150, I m just trying to understand where does "ϵ(1−γ)/2γ" come from?

Comment: is it   
||V^n+1-V*|| <= γ/(1-γ)*||V^n+1-V^n|| on the middle of the 162    and rearrangement gives us: (1-γ)/γ*|V^n+1-V*|| <=||V^n+1-V^n|| where |V^n+1-V*|| is error, and if this statement does not hold (holds ">") we must stop the iteration?

Comment: That's where it comes from, but it's not an "if this statement does not hold" thing.  It always holds; it's math.  That's the point of a proof.  In the computer code, on the other hand, you're going to specify the maximum error $|V^n-V^*|$ you're willing to live with, and the code will convert that to the cutoff value for $|V^{n+1}-V^n|$, below which you're guaranteed of not exceeding that maximum error.  The guarantee comes from the proof, as does the formula for converting the max. error you're willing to live with to the cutoff value for $|V^{n+1}-V^n|$.

Comment: You're getting closer to understanding it!